# Elasticsearch java bulk upsert exception

Tags: java, exception, elasticsearch, upsert, bulkupdate

I am trying to update an existing index in bulk, using the bulk API, so some records are existing which need to be updated and some are new, which need to be indexed since they are not there. I used the following piece of code

```
BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequestBuilder = client.prepareBulk();
bulkRequestBuilder.add(client.prepareUpdate(InvokeMain.indexName, type, docId).setUpsert(finalMap));
```

However, with this, I am getting the following exception

```
org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestValidationException: Validation      
Failed: script or doc is missing;
```

I am guessing new records/new docIds is where it fails. Any idea how to achieve upsert (update if exists, insert if not) in bulk?

Comment: Can you show how `finalMap` looks like? Can you try with `prepareIndex` instead?

Comment: It's a map of the elasticsearch column name and the value is an object, which can be further a map or string or list or anything. Map<String,Object>. I use the same to create the index, works fine. Even update of existing records works fine (changing the above snippet to have 'setDoc(finalMap)' instead of setUpsert.)

Comment: Also, prepareIndex I use for creating the index, existing records don't get updated that way. The behaviour is erratic. Some records get changed if I give same docId while indexing, some don't. Also, prepareIndex doesn't offer upsert.

Answer (score 2):

```
BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequestBuilder = client.prepareBulk();
bulkRequestBuilder.add(client.prepareUpdate(InvokeMain.indexName, type, docId).setDoc(finalMap).setUpsert(finalMap));
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `upsert` (i.e. `setUpsert`), your `finalMap` needs to be slightly different as [described in the official docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts), namely it must contain a `doc` (your case) or a `script` (hence the validation error stating that `script` or `doc` is missing):

```
...
Map<String, Object> docMap = ... your current map containing the fields...;
Map<String, Object> finalMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
finalMap.put("doc", docMap);
...
```

Comment: How is the same code working while creating the index then? The finalMap is nothing but the document source. Not all fields of it are indexed. When I create the index, using prepareIndex, I use the same code snippet where I have prepareIndex(indexname, type, docId) and the finalMap as the source. The finalMap doesn't have the docId itself as I don't need that in the source of the document. And it also works for update.

Comment: This works for update:
bulkRequestBuilder.add(client.prepareUpdate(InvokeMain.indexName, type, docId).setDoc(finalMap)). How then?

Comment: Since you're using `setUpsert` in your code above, all I'm saying is that you cannot pass your doc map directly, but you need to pass it as a sub-map to the `doc` key.